# Strange behavior with brackets in path

Tags: powershell, path

There is a strange behavior with PowerShell when there are square brackets in a path. For instance, if you are in the folder:

```
C:\Some Movie [2011]
```

which contains an `mkv` file and you type:

```
ls *.mkv
```

nothing is returned! I think the problem lies with the fact that PowerShell tries to do something like:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Some Movie [2011]\*.mkv'
```

which fails because `[2011]` is considered a wildcard. I was able to retrive all `mkv` from such a folder with the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\Some Movie [2011]' -Include *.mkv
```

but when I try to feed those results in a Rename-Item command it fails.

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\Some Movie [2011]' -Include *.mkv | Rename-Item -NewName "movie.mkv"
```

The same operations in a folder without brackets runs without problems. Any ideas?

Comment: What if the folder contain more than one mkv file? You can't rename them all to movie.mkv.

Comment: Yes, I have only one `mkv` file, I just don't know it's name so I need a wildcard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See my comment on your question (above). this will work if as you expect in case there's only one mkv file in that folder. `Rename-Item` doesn't support LiterlPath (fixed in v3), you can resort to .NET. I also recommend (when you filter for just one extension) to use -Filter instead of Include, it performs faster.

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\Some Movie [2011]' -Filter *.mkv | Foreach-Object{
    $NewName = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath 'movie.mkv'
    [System.IO.File]::Move($_.FullName,$NewName)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a known bug in the Rename-Item cmdlet [that doesn't handle filenames with brackets](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=277707&SiteID=99).  In the link, scroll-down to the "Posted by Microsoft on 01/29/2010".

The work-around is to use the Move-Item cmdlet instead, as Move-Item has a "-LiteralPath" option.  The catch though, is that it apparently works only if the directory name does not contain brackets, which doesn't sound like it'll help your case.

I'm not sure, but you could try something similar from DOS (cmd).  Otherwise, you might be stuck with executing renames from within a .Net language, as you could definitely make it work there.

It looks like Microsoft just released [Powershell 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27548) a few days ago.  No promises, but you could try installing that and see if they managed to get the bug fixed.